# Control may reach end of non-void function ...Error in implementing binary search

Tags: c, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search on an array. I tried to get rid of this error that I get while compiling but could not. This is the function that I made for binary search:

```
bool BinSearch(int key, int Array[], int min, int max)
{
    if (max < min)
    return false;

    else
    {

        int mid = (min + max)/2 ;

        if (key > Array[mid])
            BinSearch(key, Array, mid+1, max);

        else if (key < Array[mid])
            BinSearch(key, Array, min, mid-1);

        else
            return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: `return BinSearch(...`

Comment: Well, what does the function return if `max < min` is false and `key > Array[mid]` is true?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a tip for the future I would include the error message in your post and not use quite so much bold. To answer your question you're not returning the value of BinSearch() so it's possible to reach the end of the function without returning control to the main method.

Comment: Okay, it works fine now.Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake is you are missing a return statement for your recursive calls to `BinSearch`.  To make this explanation easier to understand I have added some parenthesis in your code to make everything more explicit.  Note the code below is the same as your code, just with some (redundant) parentheses and more appropriate indentation.

Now lets assume we have a code path where `max < min` is `false` followed by `key > Array[mid]` being `true`.  Therefore we have the following program execution, annotated in the code:

```
bool BinSearch(int key, int Array[], int min, int max)
{
    if (max < min) { // Step 1, false
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // Step 2, start the else block
        int mid = (min + max)/2 ;

        if (key > Array[mid]) { // Step 3, true
            BinSearch(key, Array, mid+1, max); // Step 4 call BinSearch
            // Step 5, finished with call to BinSearch
        }
        else if (key < Array[mid]) {
            BinSearch(key, Array, min, mid-1);
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        // Step 6, Done with else block
    }
// Step 7, Done with function, no return statement
}
```

A similar thing would happen if `key > Array[mid]` is `false` and `key < Array[mid]` is `true`.  This should make it clear why your compiler correctly thinks there are code paths that do not have a return.  The solution, as previously pointed out in the comments is to do `return BinSearch(...)`.